# Setting command Listener

Tags: java-me

I am trying to set a command listener on a particular list in J2ME. While other commands in other displayables in the application works fine, the commands on this particular list don't work. I dont seem to get where I am making a mistake. Below is the code for the List.

```
 List menuList() {

    if (mList == null) {

        mList = new List("Services", List.IMPLICIT);
       //............ the list items are appended
    } else {
       //............this will display the existing list
    }
    mList.addCommand(BACK_COMMAND);
    mList.addCommand(EXIT_COMMAND);
    mList.setCommandListener(this);
    return mList;
}
```

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: please post more details or your complete class.

Comment: @AliPour thanks but that method is the only method that has the problem.